# How do I export a node.js module which is inside the Promise.all (somefunction) . then (function (){})

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise

How do I export a node.js module which is inside the Promise.all (somefunction) . then (function (){})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you can do is export the promise and wait for it in the other file:

```
// index1.js
…

module.exports = Promise.all(ted);
```

```
// index2.js
require('./index1').then(getStatus => {
    console.log(getStatus);
    …
});
```

Comment: Sorry, typo. You need to refer to the callback parameter of course.

Comment: Add a timer where? There's no place you could add a timer to my code that would make it behave differently.

Comment: Yes. You need to place all code that should wait for `index1.js` inside the `then` callback.

Comment: your index2 does `require` itself instead of index1?

Comment: No idea. Maybe because you're calling `db.close()` before the thing is found? Also I'm not sure what your operation in index1 is (you didn't post that code), or why you're sure that the problem comes from executing `p()` while the insertion hasn't finished yet.

Comment: But did the promise actually resolve at the right time, and was *that* promise awaited?

Comment: Yeah, as I expected - you are calling `savemongo(myobj,str)` but there's no attempt to wait for it to finish. Also, you `resolve` your `ted` promises regardless what the status of the distance matrix in that callback is.

Comment: Oh yea Even i realised that . Thank you @bergi Appreciate your help.. thank you :)

Comment: You might want to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about that, providing the relevant part of the code.

Comment: Because I thought promise.all waits for all the async operation to finish

Comment: All async operations whose promises it was passed (in fact, it doesn't even know about the operations, it only waits for the promises to settle). Not all async operations arbitrarily occuring anywhere.

Comment: Thank you .I have asked a new question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928459/how-do-i-nest-a-promise-inside-another-promise-function-in-node-js