# How do i nest a promise inside another promise function in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

I have a file file which is surrounded by Promise function . I have a database operation inside this function which requires another promise too . Please check the code below

```
var p ;
var ted = dep.map(function(name){

return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){ 
    /*..list of other tasks*/
    for(int i = 0 ;i<3<;i++){        
      p = Promise.resolve(savemongo(myobj,str));  // this is async function. How do I wait till this operation is complete and then move to next
    } 
  resolve();

)};
```

Now i have to export this module to a different file

Im using the below code

```
module.exports = Promise.all([ted,p]);
```

How do I wait till my savetomongodb function is complete .

Comment: `Promise.all` only takes one argument. By the way, please format/indent your code properly.

Comment: @karthik006 You can't ask someone specifically to help you. Stack Overflow is a community, anyone can answer and ask. You don't get to ask a specific someone to help you...

Comment: Sorry guys I have updated the question above

Comment: Does `savetomongodb()` call  return a `Promise`?

Comment: Your loop doesn't make sense, you're not using `i` and `param1` and `param2` aren't defined anywhere visible

Comment: @guest271314 please check the updated code

Comment: @SterlingArcher thats just a format of how my code look like

Comment: What is the return value of `savetomongodb()` function call?

Comment: @guest271314 please check my updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surrounding the whole thing by one `new Promise` call doesn't help anything. Inside it, you'd still have callback hell. And no, throwing `Promise.resolve()` at a function that doesn't return anything doesn't help either.

You will need to [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) the asynchronous primitives, i.e. the smallest parts that are asynchronous. In your case, that's `distance.matrix` and mongo's `connect`+`insert`:

```
function getMatrix(m, o, d) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        m.matrix(o, d, function(err, distances) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else     resolve(distances);
        });
    });
}

function save(url, store, k) {
// cramming connect+insert in here is not optimal but let's not get into unnecessary detail
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            if (err)
                reject(err);
            else
                db.collection(k).insert(store, function(err, results) {
                    if (err) reject(err);
                    else     resolve(results);
                    db.close();
                });
        });
    });
}
```

Now that we have those, we can actually use them and combine our promises into what you actually are looking for:

```
module.exports = Promise.all(dep.map(function(name) {
    distance.departure_time(name);
    return getMatrix(distance, origins, destinations).then(function(distances) {
        if (!distances) throw new Error('no distances');
        var promises = [];
        if (distances.status == 'OK') {
            for (var i=0; i < origins.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < destinations.length; j++) {
                    var origin = distances.origin_addresses[i];
                    var destination = distances.destination_addresses[j];
                    if (distances.rows[0].elements[j].status == 'OK') {
                        var duration = distances.rows[i].elements[j].duration_in_traffic.value;
                        var myobj = {
                            destination: destination,
                            departure_time: name,
                            duration: duration
                        };
                        var str = destination.replace(/[,\s]+/g, '');
                        promises.push(save(url, myobj, str));
//                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return Promise.all(promises); // now wait for all save results
    });
}));
```

Comment: What are the differences, if any, between `throw new Error('no distances')` and `return Promise.reject(new Error('no distances'))`? Should `.catch()` be chained to `return Promise.all(promises)`?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bergi . You saved my day . ALso I didnt understand the part where you are using the promises array to push the save function. Can you please clarify it if you dont mind

Comment: 1) [Not a difference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33445415/1048572). 2) `catch` should be chained to where you want to handle errors. (Chaining it to `Promise.all(promises)` will catch the ones from the `save` calls). 3) Not pushing the `save` function, *calling* the `save` function and putting the returned promise into that array. Just like what you originally did with the `dep.map(…)`

Comment: Excellent solution